# Can doxygen reference an unqualified java classname from a markdown file?

Tags: doxygen

I have created a markdown file with the `.md` extension

I have figured out how to include a link to fully qualified java class

### works

```
see [AmazingClass](@ref com.very.AmazingClass)
```

### would like to do

```
see [AmazingClass](@ref AmazingClass)
```

is this possible?

Comment: the reason is in the future it is possible that a linked class might move packages

Comment: I also seem to have a problem from regular java classes' javadocs with most (but not all) java {@link } references to clases, some work - most don't (there I'm usuing regular html javadoc format, not markdown - this javadoc is in the same output documentation as the original question)